# C code with openmp called from R gives inconsistent results

Tags: r, openmp

Below is a piece of C code run from R used to compare each row of a matrix to a vector. The number of identical values is stored in the first column of a two-column matrix.
I know it can easily be done in R (as done to check the results), but this is a first step for a more complex use case.
When openmp is not used, it works ok. When openmp is used, it give correlated (0.99) but inconsistent results.
*Question1:* What am I doing wrong?
*Question2:* I use a double for loop to fill the output matrix (ret) with zeros. What would be a better solution?

Also, inconsistencies were observed when the code was used in a package. I tried to make the code reproducible using `inline`, but it does not recognize the openmp statements (I tried to include 'omp.h', in the parameters of `cfunction`, ...).
*Question3:* How can we make this code work with `inline`?

I'm (too?) far outside my comfort zone on this topic.

```r
library(inline)

compare <- cfunction(c(x = "integer", vec = "integer"), "
  const int I = nrows(x), J = ncols(x);
  SEXP ret;
  PROTECT(ret = allocMatrix(INTSXP, I, 2));
  int *ptx = INTEGER(x), *ptvec = INTEGER(vec), *ptret = INTEGER(ret);

  for (int i=0; i<I; i++)
      for (int j=0; j<2; j++)
          ptret[j * I + i] = 0;

  int i, j;

  #pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(ptx, ptvec, ptret) private(i,j)

  for (j=0; j<J; j++)
   for (i=0; i<I; i++)
      if (ptx[i + I * j] == ptvec[j]) {++ptret[i];}

  UNPROTECT(1);
  return ret;
")


N = 3e3
M = 1e4
m = matrix(sample(c(-1:1), N*M, replace = TRUE), nc = M)
v = sample(-1:1, M, replace = TRUE)

cc = compare(m, v)
cr = rowSums(t(t(m) == v))
all.equal(cc[,1], cr)
```

Comment: You are not using Rcpp so I would suggest to remove the Rcpp tag.

Comment: At first glance it seems that there is a data race at `++ptret[i]`.  Each thread will run over every value of `i`, so the updates will be uncoordinated and, approximately, chaotic.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I need to check more carefully the openmp clauses.

Comment: What does the inner loop is a reduction and there is an omp clause for that. Presenttly it is incorrect and explains your problems. But reductions ony apply to vars, not array elements like in your situation. What can be done is to have global matrix, with a line per thread. This line is a local vector and accumulation can be done per thread without problems. And you add a second omp parallel for to accumulate per columns. Can again be done without precautions. To get thread id, use omp_get_thread_num().

Comment: Thanks. It helped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above, I reconsidered the data race issue.
IIUC, my loop was parallelized on `j` (the columns). Then, each thread had its own value of `i` (the rows), but possible identical values across threads, that were then trying to increment `ptret[i]` at the same time. 
To avoid this, I now loop on `i` first, so that only a single thread will increment each row.
Then, I realized that I could move the zero-initialization of `ptret` within the first loop.
It seems to work. I get identical results, increased CPU usage, and 3-4x speedup on my laptop.
I guess that solves questions 1 and 2. I will have a closer look at the inline/openmp problem.
Code below, fwiw.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <stdio.h>

SEXP c_compare(SEXP x, SEXP vec)
{
  const int I = nrows(x), J = ncols(x);
  SEXP ret;
  PROTECT(ret = allocMatrix(INTSXP, I, 2));
  int *ptx = INTEGER(x), *ptvec = INTEGER(vec), *ptret = INTEGER(ret);

  int i, j;
#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(ptx, ptvec, ptret) private(i, j)
  for (i = 0; i < I; i++) {
    // init ptret to zero
    ptret[i] = 0;
    ptret[I + i] = 0;

    for (j = 0; j < J; j++)
      if (ptx[i + I * j] == ptvec[j]) {
        ++ptret[i];
      }
    }

  UNPROTECT(1);
  return ret;
}
```